# Bootstrap navbar not loading properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and I recently used one of their templates,all works well, but my navbar is not loading properly, it SHOULD look like this:
[What i Should be getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq9wW.png)

But it looks like this in both chrome and firefox:
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tYut.png)

and this is my html (only the nav part)

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your CSS isn't loading correctly.  Try adding this to your page <head> from http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It's just a copy of Bootstrap.  If that works, then you know the problem is with your local copy (if you're using one, or your CDN), if it doesn't then the problem lies elsewhere.

EDIT: I should edit to say that I've tested the code you provided on another website, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I don't think importing `bootstrap-theme` is necessary. also you could import jQuery at the top to make the menu button work on mobile screens.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on jsfiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/ajrvrtz6/
```

I used: 
butstrap v3.3

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/…; integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg‌​4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh‌​4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript --> 
<script src="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/…; integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mC‌​WNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7T‌​xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```