# Bootstrap not working: Navbar not loading properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Soo, I am a beginner at Bootstrap. I am making a website for my app. The sidebar works properly (Its not bootstrap sidebar, I have made it on my own). But the navbar doesn't work at all. If I use 5.1.0 Then Only the toggle button and Name show. And the name isn't completely shown. And If I use older versions then it just positions them randomly and sets their color to blue.

I am right now using the boiler-code to test.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Imports:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="class.css">
    <script src="class.js"></script>
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The first 2 are my own codes for the sidebar. Also if required pls tell if I need to post my entire code.

EDIT: [Bootstrap navbar not loading properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044961/bootstrap-navbar-not-loading-properly)

Similar Question, but the answers in this one don't work

Comment: Did you add jquery ? you should add it aswell. ref -> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp

Answer (score -1):

Oops! I am a really big idiot. I wasn't using jsfiddle. I tried it. It works now. But I have 1 more issue: If I use dark bg class, my text actually is still black. Does bootstrap provide this or it hat to be manually coded?